# Docker build failure from docker file

Tags: python, docker

i am trying to build my first docker image but I keep getting an error saying `failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: Dockerfile parse error line 2: FROM requires either one or three arguments`

My docker file looks as below:

```
#Pull base image
FROM python: 3.7

#set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYCODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

#set work directory
WORKDIR /code

#Install dependencies
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /code/
RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system

# copy project
COPY . /code/
```

any ideas on this? it doesn't seem to be getting past line 2 for some reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`FROM python: 3.7`

Due to the whitespace between `python:` and `3.7`, `FROM` receives 2 arguments (`python:` and `3.7`) while it expects either one (in the format of `image:tag`) or three, as the error says. See the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from).

You should remove the whitespace:

`FROM python:3.7`